How can I programmatically set the value of an item in the new form of a SharePoint list?
I have a new form for a SharePoint list. this form should set some value through code. I'm using SharePoint on-premises 2019 designer new form.
HTML code of the new form element:
<tr style="visibility: hidden;">
    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">DStatus</td>
                                                                                                                                                               
       <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id ="ff32{$Pos}" ControlMode = "New"       FieldName="DRStatus" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff32',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@DRStatus')}"/>
                                                            
        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id = "ff32description{$Pos}" FieldName="DRStatus" ControlMode="New"/>
        
</td>
</tr> 

JS code to set value:
 var status = $('#Lookup id');
       var statusOption = status.find('option:eq(1)');
       var selectedStatus;          
       selectedStatus= statusOption.text(); 
       alert("DRStatus: " +selectedStatus);
        
       $("input[Title='DRStatus']").val(selectedStatus);

I have tried the approach below. It can extract the values if the column was a lookup. But cannot set/save the value for the column element in list.
Please help, how can I set the column element value directly through code without using workflow?

Are you using the classic experience list form?

no, im using modern expirience for the form

You cannot inject custom JS directly for modern list forms.

I did not know that. Thanks for letting me know.

@GaneshSanap-MVP,  is there any other way to set defualt/conditional value for  new form elements
